# EventHub EventDataBatch exceed MaxMessageSize

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs 2.0.0 NuGet to add messages to batch:

```
private EventDataBatch _currentBatch;
_currentBatch = _eventHubClient.CreateBatch();
...
var json = @event.ToEventJson();
var data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
if (_currentBatch.TryAdd(data))
            {
                return;
            }
```

But the created batch randomly (not on all created batches) throws:

> {Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.MessageSizeExceededException: The received
>   message (delivery-id:0, size:262192 bytes) exceeds the limit (262144
>   bytes) currently allowed on the link.

during

```
await _eventHubClient.SendBatchAsync(batch);
```

It is deterministic as I have set of data that throws this error always during the tests.